# Tensorflow and Multiprocessing: Passing Sessions

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I have recently been working on a project that uses a neural network for virtual robot control. I used tensorflow to code it up and it runs smoothly. So far, I used sequential simulations to evaluate how good the neural network is, however, I want to run several simulations **in parallel** to reduce the amount of time it takes to get data.

To do this I am importing python's `multiprocessing` package. Initially I was passing the sess variable (`sess=tf.Session()`) to a function that would run the simulation. However, once I get to any statement that uses this `sess` variable, the process quits without a warning. After searching around for a bit I found these two posts:
[Tensorflow: Passing a session to a python multiprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900246/tensorflow-passing-a-session-to-a-python-multiprocess)
and [Running multiple tensorflow sessions concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758669/running-multiple-tensorflow-sessions-concurrently)

While they are highly related I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work. I tried creating a session for each individual process and assigning the weights of the neural net to its trainable parameters without success. I've also tried saving the session into a file and then loading it within a process, but no luck there either.

Has someone been able to pass a session (or clones of sessions) to several processes?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you can't pass clones of Sessions between processes because there's state in C address space that Python doesn't know how to copy. But creating brand new sessions in each new process should work. I haven't used multiprocessing, but I often have couple of processes open in parallel that keep their own TensorFlow sessions

Comment: The second link I provided runs several processes in parallel, but the issue is that I need the neural network to be the same for ALL the processes.

Comment: You may be able to work-around it by using TensorFlow distributed -- ie, have a local worker and ps and create multiple sessions in parallel like `tf.Session("grpc://localhost:2222")` https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/distributed/index.md

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov , any chance you could elaborate a little bit? I am implementing parallel TRPO (Viva RL) but now working with the minimal example [ https://gist.github.com/dd210/e8bad8eadc19f44cafcdc5313a39a53f ]. Basically I would like to launch Session in main process, do some calculations, then transfer network to another X parallel processes and do some calculations in parallel there. Then repeat Y times. But I got stuck with this minimal example, because it seems that I need to work in one session all the time. Official tutorial is a <bit> vague. Appreciate any help and advice.

Comment: Multiprocessing seems to be semi-broken with TensorFlow. Here's an example of using distributed tensorflow -- https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/ea1b1bae0a75c4aae593df7eca72d9ca

Comment: BTW, I've seen people use TF with MPI before, it's fine if you launch processes and create sessions in each process separately and use MPI to communicate, as opposed to importing tensorflow -> creating session -> fork

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Exactly! I was one of such persons, but it is clearly very strange workaround.. And not perfect fit for my task either. Thank you for the example, I will look into it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't use Python multiprocessing to pass a TensorFlow `Session` into a `multiprocessing.Pool` in the straightfoward way because the `Session` object can't be pickled (it's fundamentally not serializable because it may manage GPU memory and state like that).

I'd suggest parallelizing the code using [actors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model), which are essentially the parallel computing analog of "objects" and use used to manage state in the distributed setting.

[Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray) is a good framework for doing this. You can define a Python class which manages the TensorFlow `Session` and exposes a method for running your simulation.

```
import ray
import tensorflow as tf

ray.init()

@ray.remote
class Simulator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        self.simple_model = tf.constant([1.0])

    def simulate(self):
        return self.sess.run(self.simple_model)

# Create two actors.
simulators = [Simulator.remote() for _ in range(2)]

# Run two simulations in parallel.
results = ray.get([s.simulate.remote() for s in simulators])
```

Here are a few more examples of [parallelizing TensorFlow with Ray](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-ray-with-tensorflow.html).

See the [Ray documentation](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest). Note that I'm one of the Ray developers.

Comment: Thank you so much for this - I'd like to vouch that this also (maybe obviously) works with Keras. I needed a way to run prediction in multiple processes at once. My specific implementation entailed creating wrapper classes around my Keras models, each having their own `tf.Graph()` and `tf.Session()` objects, and creating a `ray` actor from an entry point module which exposes a single `run_prediction()` method.

Answer (score 14):

I use keras as a wrapper with tensorflow as a backed, but the same general principal should apply.

If you try something like this:

```
import keras
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool

def ModelFunc(i,SomeData):
    YourModel = Here
    return(ModelScore)

pool = Pool(processes = 4)
for i,Score in enumerate(pool.imap(partial(ModelFunc,SomeData),range(4))):
    print(Score)
```

It will fail.  However, if you try something like this:

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool

def ModelFunc(i,SomeData):
    import keras
    YourModel = Here
    return(ModelScore)

pool = Pool(processes = 4)
for i,Score in enumerate(pool.imap(partial(ModelFunc,SomeData),range(4))):
    print(Score)
```

It should work.  Try calling tensorflow separately for each process.

Comment: this just saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: You are a life-saver, this works like a charm! (The 'penalty' of loading my model several times is not even one permille of total computing time.) Than you!